# How can I search the md5 checksum?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I am working with the Python Google Drive SDK for Google App Engine, and I am trying to figure out how to search by the file checksum.

It seems that Google already generates md5 checksums for every file, and I would like to use that as a first check to avoid possible file duplication.

Anyone can lend some help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, md5sum is not one of the [searchable parameters](https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters). Your app will need to retrieve the md5sums via [files.list()](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) and index them internally in order to perform such a search. Because the md5sum will change with every modification, this could prove to be pretty time consuming.

If you can offer more details about your full use case, there may be a better way to achieve your goals.